# Is there any way to force browser to SHOW CACHED IMAGE, without asking server, on newly created img?

Tags: javascript, caching

I'll try to be as short and as clear as possible:

Example HTML:

```
<span id="xyz">
   <img src="/somescript.php?x=1&y=2" />
</span>
```

Javascript (attached to `window.onload`, so it executes only after everything on page was successfully loaded):

```
    tmp=document.getElementById('xyz');
    tmp.innerHTML='<img src="/somescript.php?x=1&y=2" />';
```

`somescript.php` always generates new image on request (even with same `GET` parameters) AND returns it with `no-cache` header (**as intended and it shouldn't be changed**).

Current behaviour: browser (tested in chrome) always asks server for `/somescript.php?x=1&y=2` for each newly created image.

Is there any way to do so, that **newly created image** would show cached content if any image with such `src` has already been loaded before **without even trying to ask server for the second time** (because server will return new image, instead of old)?

P.S.: It's more of theoretical question, because **I know, that the common solution is to check/alter old `img`'s `src` instead of creating a new one**, however I want to know whether is there an answer to my actual question.

P.P.S: I haven't been able to find answer to this on google/stack mainly because the most popular question with exactly the same keywords is exactly opposite to mine.

Comment: how about having the php script return the images as data urls, then store them in sessionStorage on the browser

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion, still I'm wondering, whether is there client-side only solution (as you see there is no php in tags).

Comment: you are using a php script to return the images, the caching stuff would be solely on the front end

Comment: Well, this will require either changes in .php file (to return base64 encoded images) or reading raw data with **synchronous** `xmlhttprequest` (to ensure that the first image will load as intended - before `window.onload` fires) which is interesting, but not very nice solution to me.